# Unable to lazily load child components using angular 6

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am trying to work lazy loading in angular 6,although I have angular 7 installed in my system which is not working so far and I am not able to find answer, so needed some guidence

I have a module as `manager` which will redirect user to manager module. I want to make sure it gets loaded lazily and with below code I am not able to make it work. I am new to angular and any help will be usefull. kindly look

**app-routing.module**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'manager', loadChildren: "./manager/manager.module#ManagerModule" },
      { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];

**manager-routing.module**

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ManagerComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "/manager/home", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "home", component: ManagerHomeComponent }
    ]
  }
]
```

**manager-module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ManagerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ManagerRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule
  ]
})
```

I have not added *ManagerComponent* and *ManagerHomeComponent* to **app.module**

Kindly check and please point me on direction where I can solve this.

Note: To check lazy loading I am using a tool with chrome called **augury**

update:
**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    InventoryModule,
    PosModule,
    UserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you call `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` added it to the imports and exports array of your manager-routing.module?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Yes, It is already there. Thanks

Comment: Will you be able to replicate this on a Sample StackBlitz and share it across?

Comment: there is so much of code, I can add this to git,

Comment: post your app.module.ts contents also. Did you import something from the manager module, straight into app module? Because this could result in angular combining the two modules.

Comment: How many chunks are emitted by webpack? Have you changed the preloading strategy?

Comment: @FifthEon I have added app.module

Comment: @SiddAjmera Shall I post code on git and pate link here?

Comment: @BennettHardwick I do not know how to do that

Comment: You could try making a small example that demonstrates your problem using https://stackblitz.com/ instead of sharing your repo

Comment: Are you a 100% sure that LL is not working, could you perhaps check your chrome network tab to see if navigating to 'manager/home', results in a .js file being downloaded (on first navigation)? Augury is fine, but the network tab is lower level.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules, please recheck the "Confirm it’s working" part from this tutorial. Maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 3):

One or both of the following could be the issues:

1. You forgot to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `manager.component.html`
2. You forgot to call RouterModule.forRoot in the AppRoutingModule or RouterModule.forChild in your ManagerRoutingModule.

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-loading-example-in-angular-7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmanager%2Fmanager-routing.module.ts) for your ref.

Comment: and yes, this was the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @user_xyz.LOL, glad I could help. Please consider marking this as a solution( ✅) to close the loop. Thanks.

Comment: Can a lazily loaded module have a lazy child? Like, you'd put a lazily loaded module route under children array of a lazily loaded parent's route.